# Отправка почтовго сообщения из кода

Tags: golang, sendmail

Может кто знает, как отправить сообщение из кода в Go?

Answer (score 4):

Примерно так

```
package main

import ( 
    "log" 
    "smtp" 
)

func main() { 
    auth := smtp.PlainAuth("", "some@ya.ru", "password", "smtp.yandex.ru") 
    err := smtp.SendMail("smtp.yandex.ru:25", auth, "from@ya.ru", []string{"to@ya.ru"}, []byte("Текст письма.")) 
    if err != nil { 
        log.Fatal(err) 
    } 
}
```

Еще примеры здесь: [SendingMail](http://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/SendingMail).

Answer (score 0):

а лучше так, ибо тут есть и сабж и тело письма и нужные заголовки, ибо потом будете ломать голову, почему все настроено, но письма все равно улетают в спам.

```
SendMail("localhost:25", "from@mail.test", "Subject text", "Body text", []string{"to1@tomail.com", "to2@tomail.com"})
func SendMail(addr, from, subject, body string, to []string) error {
    r := strings.NewReplacer("\r\n", "", "\r", "", "\n", "", "%0a", "", "%0d", "")

    c, err := smtp.Dial(addr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
        defer c.Close()
    if err = c.Mail(r.Replace(from)); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    for i := range to {
        to[i] = r.Replace(to[i])
        if err = c.Rcpt(to[i]); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    w, err := c.Data()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    msg := "To: " + strings.Join(to, ",") + "\r\n" +
        "From: " + from + "\r\n" +
        "Subject: " + subject + "\r\n" +
        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n" +
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n" +
        "\r\n" + base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString([]byte(body))

    _, err = w.Write([]byte(msg))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = w.Close()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return c.Quit()
}
```